# Speed-up the computation of this sum of small matrices

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, summation

Given a matrix `mat` with a large number of rows (a few thousands) and a few columns (between 2 and 10), I'd like to compute the sum of the "small" matrices obtained by taking the dot product of each row (index `i`) and the transpose of the delayed row (index `i+p`):

```
Sum[Transpose[{mat[[i]]}].{mat[[i + p]]}, {i, 1, n - p}]
```

The above implementation is surely not optimal and takes quite some time to compute. How can I make it more efficient?

Example code:

```
n = 20000;
mat = RandomReal[{0, 5}, {n, 3}];
f[p_] := Sum[Transpose[{mat[[i]]}].{mat[[i + p]]}, {i, 1, n - p}]
Array[f, 100]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* about 15 seconds *)
```

Note: in signal processing,`f` corresponds to what is called *correlation matrix function* but I did not find an efficient way of using the function `Correlation`.

---

**Edit: comparison of the answers** Here is a comparison of the original solution and the two answers (*log* plot). It appears tom's answer is by far the most efficient.

[image: comparison graph]

Code used for the benchmark:

```
original[p_, mat_] := 
  With[{n = Length[mat]}, 
   Sum[Transpose[{mat[[i]]}].{mat[[i + p]]}, {i, 1, n - p}]];
drbelisarius[p_, mat_] := 
  With[{n = Length[mat]}, 
   Inner[Times, mat[[1 ;; n - p]], mat[[p + 1 ;; n]], Plus, 1]];
tom[p_, mat_] := Transpose[mat[[;; -(p + 1)]]].mat[[p + 1 ;;]];
compareStep[p_, mat_] := 
 Map[AbsoluteTiming[#[p, mat];] &, {original, drbelisarius, 
    tom}][[All, 1]]
SeedRandom[6666]
compare[n_] := Block[{mat = RandomReal[{0, 5}, {n, 3}]},
  Array[compareStep[#, mat] &, n - 1] // Total]
tab = Array[compare, 300][[2 ;; -1]];
ListLogPlot[Transpose@tab, AxesLabel -> {"n", "time"}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"original", "drbelisarius", "tom"}]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write the summation and the outer product as a matrix multiplication:

```
f2[p_] := Transpose[mat[[;; -(p + 1)]]].mat[[p + 1 ;;]]
```

Comment: Your code is much more efficient (see edit in OP). I will accept it if no (even) better solution come.

Comment: @anderstood, dot products are quite efficient; I doubt that this solution here can be beaten.

Answer (score 4):

```
ff[p_] := Inner[Times, mat[[1 ;; n - p]], mat[[p + 1 ;; n]], Plus, 1]
```

Seems 3x faster